# MySQL insert into ALL rows of one column from left joined table?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, create-table

I'm having difficulty with an INSERT statement where I provide the values for the first four columns. The fifth (last) column is supposed to concatenate two columns of another table. That part works fine, but only for one row. Both tables are to have 12 rows (hence the 12 literal values), but **how do I** make the joined subquery return **all of its rows** for the one column I'm trying to insert (thereby corresponding with the values in the other columns)?

Have tried numerous methods, but here's what it looks like now...

```
    INSERT INTO properties (property_id, condo_type, pets, internet, owner_name)
      SELECT 
    '301S', '207S', '1100T', '1201S', '317T', '110S', '1010S', '409T', '505T', '1005S', '656S', '942S' AS property_id,
    'SandsOF3BR', 'SandsOF3BR', 'SandsOF2BR', 'Tides3BR', 'SandsOF2BR', 'Tides2BR', 'SandsOF2BR', 'SandsOF2BR', 'Tides2BR', 'Tides3BR', 'SandsOF2BR', 'SandsOF3BR' AS condo_type,
    1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0 AS pets,
    1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0 AS internet,
    CONCAT(owner_first_name, ' ', owner_last_name) AS owner_name
      FROM owners LEFT JOIN properties 
        ON owners.property_id = properties.property_id
      WHERE owners.property_id = properties.property_id;
```

So basically, the properties table and the owners table both have data in their respective "property_id" columns, reflecting which property belongs to what owner. What I mean is, do I have to create a procedure to loop through the second table, or is there a more conventional method? Or am I going about populating this column all wrong? Please help, thanks... ANYBODY??

Comment: Please provide data at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to build the schema in sqlfiddle but I get the same error that occurs in executing the script:  "Schema Creation Failed: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". I actually had success using a different method, retrieving the data in a separate insert into statement, BUT since it was a separate statement, it of course inserted it in a new row (albeit the data was right).

Comment: That's because you specify 5 columns here `INSERT INTO properties (property_id, condo_type, pets, internet, owner_name)`, but name way more than 5 in your `SELECT ...`

Comment: I was able to successfully create a schema on sqlfiddle, BUT I had to comment-out the problematic INSERT statement. The schema is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84d3b6/1

Comment: Ok, so I think what you're saying is that I need to populate the table "one row at a time"? What I've tried to do here is to fill all fields of all columns in one statement. For example, "1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0 AS internet" is supposed to fill 12 rows of the column "internet" with this set of values.  Can one not do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO properties
            (property_id,   /*here*/
             condo_type,    /*you*/
             pets,          /*name*/
             internet,      /*5*/
             owner_name)    /*columns*/

SELECT '301S',              /*here you name way more than the 5 columns*/
       '207S',              /*from your insert statement.*/
       '1100T',              
       '1201S',             /*So, where to put them? MySQL doesn't know*/
       '317T',              /*That's why you get an error.*/
       '110S',
       '1010S',
       '409T',
       '505T',
       '1005S',
       '656S',
       '942S'                                         AS property_id,
       'SandsOF3BR',
       'SandsOF3BR',
       'SandsOF2BR',
       'Tides3BR',
       'SandsOF2BR',
       'Tides2BR',
       'SandsOF2BR',
       'SandsOF2BR',
       'Tides2BR',
       'Tides3BR',
       'SandsOF2BR',
       'SandsOF3BR'                                   AS condo_type,
       1,
       1,
       0,
       0,
       0,
       0,
       0,
       1,
       1,
       1,
       1,
       0                                              AS pets,
       1,
       1,
       0,
       1,
       1,
       1,
       0,
       1,
       0,
       1,
       0,
       0                                              AS internet,
       Concat(owner_first_name, ' ', owner_last_name) AS owner_name
FROM   owners
       LEFT JOIN properties
              ON owners.property_id = properties.property_id
WHERE  owners.property_id = properties.property_id;
```

Are these 2 columns

```
       Concat(owner_first_name, ' ', owner_last_name) AS owner_name
```

from the owners table? If yes, then why do you join the `properties` table at all? There's no need to.

Write it like this:

```
INSERT INTO properties
            (property_id,
             condo_type,
             pets,
             internet,
             owner_name)
SELECT 'value1',
       'value2',
       'value3',
       'value4',
       Concat(owner_first_name, ' ', owner_last_name)
FROM   owners
;
```

This will insert all the rows from owners (just the 2 columns of course) into properties. The first 4 columns are the same for every row, since they are just strings.

If you want to insert your static strings into your table you either write multiple statements or in one statement but specifying multiple rows like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2) VALUES
(1, 2), /*first row*/
(3, 4); /*second row*/
```

**EDIT:**

To combine those two approaches you'd have to write something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO properties
            (property_id,
             condo_type,
             pets,
             internet,
             owner_name)
SELECT 
       CASE owners.property_id WHEN 1 THEN 'value1'
                               WHEN 2 THEN 'value2'
       END AS column1,
       CASE WHEN owner_first_name = 'fancy' AND owner_last_name = 'pants' THEN 'value3'
       ELSE 'value4' END AS column2,
       Concat(owner_first_name, ' ', owner_last_name) AS owner_name
FROM   owners
       LEFT JOIN properties
              ON owners.property_id = properties.property_id
WHERE  owners.property_id = properties.property_id;
```

Not really practical ;)

Comment: Thanks so much, is there a way to combine the above methods in a single statement, where I can insert multiple static strings (one is a PK by the way) and also use the select portion to insert the corresponding "owner names" on the same rows?